# File preview not working Vtiger 7.3 - i've tried 3 different servers with fresh installs

Tags: php, vtiger, vtigercrm

I seem to have an issue with the file preview in the documents which throws me a xyz and logs me out. See image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOk0g.png)

It doesn't matter what I change including removing the / from the root and site address in config php file i just cant get it to work.

Ive followed its4you install instructions with the correct chown and owner permissions etc for the full install. I then decided to set a brand new instance up on a new server and it is the same. So i reconfigured a different server on amazon web services running ubuntu... exactly the same issue.

I have a similar issue when i installed pdfmaker and tried to browse server in the editor (fck possibly), it would show me blank thumb nails, if i click one then save it would close the session and log me out.

I have several versions of 7.1 running on the same servers without issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to this. Whilst browser through two comparative server setups I noticed "Varnish" was enabled on the new instance running VTiger 7.3. I turned this off and hey presto, issue resolved!

Comment: This does not seem to resolve your problem, because you still do not know *why* it failed.  Maybe this [link](https://it-solutions4you.com/tipstricks/how-can-i-debug-my-vtiger/) comes closer to a real problem-solver.

Comment: I agree. However i did employ the services of its4you directly to try and resolve this issue, they couldn't figure out the reason. I'm no developer and simply need it to work, this works for me. Cheers Lee